# How to use Ternary Operator using Primefaces using JSF EL to render specific text when items are null?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jstl

Am using JSF Primefaces 7.0 to render an xhtml file to display a user (alongside the username inside parenthesis) if his name is null or an empty string, I wish to just show the username without the parenthesis.

---

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

---

So, right now this is what I have rendering properly:

user.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    User: #{userReport.selectedUser.name} (#{userReport.selectedUser.username})
</html>
```

---

Renders (inside a web browser):

```
User: John Doe (jdoe)
```

However, if the `#{userReport.selectedUser.name}` is null, it renders the username inside parenthesis:

```
User: (jdoe)
```

I need it to render like this (without the parenthesis) :

```
User: jdoe
```

---

Tried using the ternary operator `? :`

```
#{userReport.selectedUser.name ? userReport.selectedUser.name (#{userReport.selectedUser.username}) : #{userReport.selectedUser.username} }
```

---

This causes the following stack trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: The identifier [#] is not a valid Java identifier as required by section 1.19 of the EL specification (Identifier ::= Java language identifier). This check can be disabled by setting the system property org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK to true.
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:749)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

---

Solved it using this:

```
User:<c:choose>
         <c:when test="#{not empty userReport.selectedUser.name}">
             #{userReport.selectedUser.name} ({userReport.selectedUser.username})
          </c:when>
          <c:otherwise>
             #{userReport.selectedUser.username}
          </c:otherwise>
     </c:choose>
```

---

Is there a way to do this in a simpler way? For example, using the ternary `? :` operator?

Comment: `!isEmpty(userReport.selectedUser.name) ? ...`

Comment: Thanks Marquis, is this surrounded by ```#{}``` after ```User:```

Comment: You could use OmniFaces for this https://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Strings https://omnifaces.org/docs/vdldoc/3.8/of/parenthesize.fn.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working using the `? :` ternary operator and the `+=` concatenation operator:

```
User: #{!empty(userReport.selectedUser.name) ? userReport.selectedUser.name += ' (' += userReport.selectedUser.username += ')' : userReportView.selectedUser.username}
```